# radio button doesn't show the bullet

Tags: html, radio-button

I have a page with radio button that doesn't show the bullet only for same row (name='197' and value='_ for example') [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z3qcmf2v/1/)

E.g.

[image: radio button]
this is the code for the line

```
<tr>
    <td class="generic">197</td>
    <td class="generic">PARASPRUZZI  RUOTE POSTERIORI</td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="radio" value="S" name="197" userselection="1">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="radio" value="_" name="197" checked="">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="radio" value="N" name="197" disabled="">
    </td>
  </tr>
```

I don't see where is the mistakes, can you help me?

Comment: Why is this tagged `javascript` and `jquery`? It's just pure HTML.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't show the bullet"?

Comment: See that magical attribute `disabled`? That is why your radio button isn't biting the bullet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because further on down your code (some line ~4579) you have another set of `<input>`s with the same name `197`. One of which has the `checked` attribute:

```
<tr>
    <td class="Option_S">CMBDS</td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="Option_S">DIESEL</td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" value="S" name="197" checked="">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" value="_" name="197" disabled="">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" value="N" name="197" disabled="">
    </td>
</tr>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z3qcmf2v/3/)

Comment: That doesn't explain why the radio button is disabled (which I think is what the OP is asking--though it is slightly difficult to tell).

Comment: @ialarmedalien I think by 'bullet' the OP meant the radio button checked state. Glad to have helped Fabio.

Comment: What makes it more confusing is that this second group is in a table that has `display: none;`. So you can't see it.

Comment: @Barmar Ctrl+F is the winner in most situations.

Answer (score 1):

You have others radio with name `197` in html:

```
<tr>
    <td class="Option_S">CMBDS</td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="Option_S">DIESEL</td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" value="S" name="197" checked="">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" value="_" name="197" disabled="">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" value="N" name="197" disabled="">
    </td>
</tr>
```